# Is there a way to check how user pay(with his own account or credit card) in PayPal checkout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there a way to check how user pay(with his own account or credit card) in PayPal checkout by adaptive payments api?

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be obvious what your user paid with, due to security purposes of PayPal checkout. You can see things like Instant Transfer(paid by bank) or echeck(also paid by bank). Other than that, those payments will just show as PayPal payments.

You can, however, use this parameter in your call.

PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD

The payment method type. Specify the value InstantPaymentOnly. You can specify up to 10 payments, where n is a digit between 0 and 9, inclusive.

This would make everything Instant Payment(all payments paid by bank or by balance).